# Capturing a function call as dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, python-decorators, inspect

I'm trying to write a python function decorator, and part of my implementation is that I need to capture the function call and look through the supplied values. I already have the function signature by using `inspect.signature`, but I'm unsure how to compose it with passed arguments.

Say I had the following

```
def decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(some_function_signature_getter(func, *args, **kwargs))
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


@decorator
def foo(a, b, *_, **kwargs):
    return a+b

print(foo(1, 2))
```

How can I implement `some_function_signature_getter` such that my output is something like the following:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, '_':[], 'kwargs':{}}
3
```

Comment: What research have you done? Have you seen this: [How can I read a function's signature including default argument values?](/q/2677185/4518341)

Comment: @wjandrea seems like a duplicate to me.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel that covers getting the signature, but not binding a given call's arguments to see what goes where (not that this might not still be a dupe, but that's certainly not _all_ of it).

Comment: @wjandrea I am using signature I just haven't figured out how to compose it with the passed arguments

Comment: @user852541 note if you'd included that information in the post it would have been less likely to get closed as a duplicate (of the current target, at least). Right now `inspect` isn't referred to at all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Whenever you want to introspect function/method signatures, you can use [`inspect.signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#introspecting-callables-with-the-signature-object). In this case:

```
from inspect import signature

def decorator(func):
    sig = signature(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        bound = sig.bind(*args, **kwargs)
        bound.apply_defaults()
        print(bound.arguments)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

`*args` are a *tuple*, not a list, but otherwise this gives you what you want:

```
>>> print(foo(1, 2))
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, '_': (), 'kwargs': {}}
3
```